# Differential equations and linear algebra way

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am a beginner at differential equations. Never learned this before but do know calculus.

I am reading Section 6.3 (Systems of Differential Equations) in *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang.

At the beginning of the section:

> [image]

So, e^ut is equal e^lambda*t*x. I don't understand this part.

So, here are what I understand:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u }{\mathrm{d} t} = u(t) = {e^{ut}}
$$

And in the linear algebra:

It turns out,

$$
u(t) = e^{\lambda t}x
$$

Can anyone help to explain or let me know the key word to find the relation?

Comment: What is $x$ in your post?

Comment: If $u$ is a scalar, then $x$ is nothing but a number. Can you give more information? Where do you see this equation? What book are you reading?

Comment: I am reading 6.3 Systems of Differential Equations by gilbert strang. the book said, Ax=lambda*x, so x should be eigenvector.

Comment: Can you please add that into your post? It makes your question much clearer.

Comment: I added additional information. And thanks for you help!

Comment: I have written an answer below. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way is separation of variables. One can prove that the solution with $u(0) = x$ (in your notation) of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}u(t) = u(t)$ fulfills
$$
\int^{u(t)}_x \frac{1}{g(s)}~\mathrm{d}s= \int^t_0 h(s)~\mathrm{d}s,
$$
where $g(s) = s$ and $h(s) = 1$. This comes from the ODE being in the form
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} u(t) = g(u)h(t).
$$
I'm sure you can find the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax=\lambda x$, and $u(t)=e^{\lambda t}x$, then direct substitution tells you that
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}e^{\lambda t}x=\lambda e^{\lambda t}x=e^{\lambda t}(\lambda x)=e^{\lambda t}(Ax)=A(e^{\lambda t}x)=Au
$$

Therefore, $u(t)=e^{\lambda t}x$ solves that differential equation
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=Au.
$$